# Задача. Как соединить цифры с st, rd, nd

Tags: python

```
data = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
for age in data:
    print(age) #перебираем
   if age in data:
       print(age)
```

Вот вообще не догоняю как через цепочку if elif else соединить цифры и  st, Rd, th:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: соединяйте как строку. почитайте про 'Конкатена́ция строк'

Comment: `if age ==1 :print(str(age)+'st')` и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью словаря:

```
keys = {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'}
for age in range(9):
    try:
        print(str(age+1)+keys[age+1])
    except:
        print(str(age+1)+'th')
```

или

```
keys = {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd', 4: 'th', 5: 'th', 6: 'th', 7: 'th', 8: 'th', 9: 'th'}
for age in range(9):
    print(str(age+1)+keys[age+1])
```

Либо так

```
data = 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th'
for age in range(9):
    print(str(age+1)+data[age])
```

Ну, или если вы любители стиля "по-проще и по-длиннее"

```
for age in range(9):
    age += 1
    if age == 1:
        print(str(age)+'st')
    elif age == 2:
        print(str(age)+'nd')
    elif age == 3:
        print(str(age)+'rd')
    else:
        print(str(age)+'th')
```